# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func referenced in function "void __cdecl Padding(int)"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Using the FTDI API compiles and links fine under Visual Studio 2012.

but under VS 2014, it gives:

```
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func referenced in function "void __cdecl Padding(int)"
```

Have the standard libraries changed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard libraries have changed, and FTDI doesn't seem to care - at least not as of CDM2.12.18 driver version.

The problem is described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30412951/1329652).

The `void __cdecl Padding(int)` function from `devcon.obj` within `ftd2xx.lib` is the culprit. It references one of `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`, given as macros. The contents of these macros changed.

Since we don't really expect any I/O from the FTDI library, we might as well provide the simplest implementation possible:

```
FILE* __cdecl _imp____iob_func() { return 0; }
```

If you want a version that does what it's supposed to do:

```
FILE* __cdecl _imp____iob_func()
{
    struct _iobuf_VS2012 { // ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdio.h #56
        char *_ptr;
        int   _cnt;
        char *_base;
        int   _flag;
        int   _file;
        int   _charbuf;
        int   _bufsiz;
        char *_tmpfname; };
    // VS2015 has FILE = struct {void* _Placeholder}

    static struct _iobuf_VS2012 bufs[3];
    static char initialized = 0;

    if (!initialized) {
        bufs[0]._ptr = stdin->_Placeholder;
        bufs[1]._ptr = stdout->_Placeholder;
        bufs[2]._ptr = stderr->_Placeholder;
        initialized = 1;
    }

    return (FILE*)&bufs;
}
```