# VS2015 gsl compilation error

Tags: c, glsl, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile a c program that uses the gsl library via the Visual Studio 2015. I have tried almost everything I have found online but nothing has worked so far. 
The error I obtain is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  LNK2019 unresolved
>   external symbol ___iob_func referenced in function
>   _gsl_error    GSLExample  C:....\gsl.lib(error.obj)   1

and more alike

In particular I tried answered Aug 8 at 19:43 in

[unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf and __imp____iob_func, SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2)

More detail about how to implement this answer would be helpful

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You probably downloaded a library compiled with Visual Studio 2013 or earlier.

A change in Visual Studio 2015 broke backwards compatibility!

You just need to recompile the library with Visual Studio 2015, use that and it will work!

Comment: How do I compile the library with visual studio?