# Visual Studio 2015 unresolved external symbol __imp___environ

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2015, lnk2001

I'm migrating a Visual Studio 2013 C++ project to Visual Studio 2015 and I'm running into linker errors. My understanding is that C++ 2015 introduced breaking changes, so I may need to recompile the libs. However, I have a 3rd party lib that I cannot recompile and it has been giving me errors that I'm trying to work around. Using SO, I've been able to resolve most of the errors. Specifically, using this post [unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf and __imp____iob_func, SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2) I was able to resolve all but 1 of my errors. The last remaining linker error I have is

`Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___environ  VibrantUnmanaged    D:\Unmanaged\VibrantUnmanaged\lmgr_md.lib(l_getenv.obj) 1`

`lmgr_md.lib` is the 3rd party lib that I cannot rebuild. Is this another error that can be worked around, or am I stuck? It's not clear to me what this is actually referencing.