# SuperBible 6th edition sb6_d32.lib not found?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL using superbible 6th edition and while compiling this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sb6.h"

class my_application : public sb6::application
{
public:
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        static const GLfloat red[] = { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
    }
};
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

I'm getting a linking errors saying cannot open sb6_d32.lib
I searched the entire sb6 directory there is no sb6_d32.lib file available for it to open so that i can link it? Am i missing something?

Edit: 2 Unresolved externals

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)   OpenGL_learning E:\C++\Learning\OpenGL\OpenGL_learning\OpenGL_learning\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)    1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func referenced in function __glfwPlatformOpenWindow    OpenGL_learning E:\C++\Learning\OpenGL\OpenGL_learning\OpenGL_learning\GLFW_d32.lib(win32_window.obj)   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build it first. See `HOWTOBUILD.txt` file in your examples folder root:

> Windows / Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:
>
> Project files are included in the source archive for Visual Studio
>   2010. These will work with Professional (all tiers) and Express editions. Newer versions of Visual Studio *should* import them just
>   fine, but this is not extensively tested. Simply open the sb6.sln file
>   in Visual Studio and hit build (F7). Evertything will build and you'll
>   end up with binaries in the 'bin' directory.

**Update:** Unresolved externals.

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in
>   function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Lets see `DECLARE_MAIN` macro implementation in the `sb6.h`:

```
#if defined _WIN32
#define DECLARE_MAIN(a)                             \
sb6::application *app = 0;                          \
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,           \
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,       \
                     LPSTR lpCmdLine,               \
                     int nCmdShow)                  \
{                                                   \
    a *app = new a;                                 \
    app->run(app);                                  \
    delete app;                                     \
    return 0;                                       \
}
```

If you want to use this macro, your program should be compiled as windows application (`/SYBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`), you are creating console application which is not supported. Change subsystem in your project settings (Linker/System).

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
>   referenced in function __glfwPlatformOpenWindow

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2) for the ways to solve that problem. In short you have to recompile all used static libraries with your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks that worked! now i'm getting 2 unresolved externals

Comment: Which symbols *exactly* linker is unable to resolve?

Comment: @psraganvesh Updated answer.

Comment: That worked for the first error but in the second one how do i recompile? because all that i have is GLFW_d32.lib file.

Comment: It source is in the /extern/glfw-2.7.6 folder.

Comment: There doesn't seems to be a source file in that directory?

Comment: https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/tree/master/extern/glfw-2.7.6

Comment: I cant seem to understand how do it, can you go in a little bit more detail (I'm sorry if I'm bothering you!)

Comment: You have to open Visual Studio command prompt, navigate to this folder and run `compile.bat`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122164/discussion-between-psrag-anvesh-and-ari0nhh).