# printf is defined in which library in EWDK 1703 version

Tags: windows

I am trying build my application but getting error _printf , _sscanf etc unresolved external symbols.
I am linking CRT libcurtl.lib still compiler cries for unresolved external symbols

Comment: about this cries not compiler but linker. you need simply search for `_printf`, `_sscanf` in lib files - look which containing this symbols (case sensetive)

Answer (score 1):

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx

> The `printf` and `scanf` family of functions are now defined inline. The
>   definitions of all of the printf and scanf functions have been moved
>   inline into `<stdio.h>`, `<conio.h>`, and other *CRT* headers. This is a
>   breaking change that leads to a linker error (*LNK2019, unresolved*
>   *external symbol*) for any programs that declared these functions
>   locally without including the appropriate CRT headers. If possible,
>   you should update the code to include the CRT headers (that is, add
>   `#include <stdio.h>`) and the inline functions, but if you do not want to modify your code to include these header files, an alternative
>   solution is to add an additional library to your linker input,
>   **legacy_stdio_definitions.lib**.

so most simply solution - include **legacy_stdio_definitions.lib** to linker input

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func referenced in function _PrintMessage
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
can you suggest some solution for this?

Comment: @AyushGupta - solution is very simply - you need search `*.lib` files which containing `___iob_func` (case sensitive). simply binary search. i for example found it *ntstc_msvcrt.lib* and *ntstc_libcmt.lib* from sdk/wdk folder. you can use it. also look like you use old code, old crt headers, but try use more new crt libs. in old crt libs (*msvcrt*, *libcmt* ) exist `___iob_func` but in modern libs - no. look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2)