# Unresolved symbol `__imp__iob`, not `__imp___iob`

Tags: visual-c++, msvcrt

I'm compiling a program with Visual Studio 2017 that links with the precompiled static version of libusb, available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.21/libusb-1.0.21.7z/download).

When I tried to link it I got some unresolved symbols like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2) and the answers pointed me to `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` which resolved all of the linker errors *except*:

```
unresolved external symbol __imp__iob
```

[This page from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt743084.aspx) talks about `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` and says it provides `__imp___iob` but doesn't mention `__imp__iob` (note the different number of underscores).

What's going on here?

(Also, yes mixing CRT versions is a bad idea and I should really compile libusb from source. I know.)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with libusb on VS2018 - 32bit, this helped me:

1. **Hacky solution**: Linker complains about some missing function -- *so just give it to it* -- such function should return the implementation defined [IO function pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/iob). For statically linked libusb-1.0 I had to add the following to my code:

   ```
   #pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib")
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   FILE iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };
   extern "C" {
       FILE * __cdecl _iob(void) { return iob; }
   }
   #endif
   ```
2. **Better solution**:
   Simply recompile static libs under VS 2018 (which I assume you are also using) and follow carefully the Readme file attached.

Comment: Yeah in the end I gave up and compiled libusb myself.