# wrap a library in a vs2013 project to be used in vs2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, wrapper

My c++ project is using TIBCO's TIBRV library (namely libtibrv.lib, libtibrvcpp.lib), TIBRV x64 version files were compiled by vs10, previously my project was compiled in VS2013 and everything is fine.

Now, when I upgrade my project to VS2017, an LNK2001 error is triggered saying "unresolved external symbol __iob_func referenced ", this is due to Microsoft changed its CRT pathes and libraries (see 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/ ) since VS 2015.

However, as there is no maintenance agreement anymore, TIBCO wouldn't provide a x64 TIBRV version compiled in VS2017.

Hence I wonder, is there a way to wrap the TIBRV x64 library files (libtibrv.lib, libtibrvcpp.lib) compiled under VS10, in VS2013, then called from VS2017? How to do that?

Comment: Don't think possible, but vc2015 and vc2017 libraries are binary compatible. So future is bright.

Comment: @seccpur it’s not bright... old lib can’t compile in vs2015+

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/rendezvous/8.3.1_january_2011/pdf/tib_rv_cpp_reference.pdf), libtibrvcppmd.lib and libtibrvmd.lib are linked dynamically to the standard library.  If the conditions are right, there's a chance that you might at least clear the CRT error by using those.

Comment: @JackC. but we compile as "MT"

Comment: Yes, you would have to switch to /MD.  I don't know if that's really hard or not.

Comment: You could perhaps write a wrapper that exports the functionality you want and then compile it as a DLL under VS 2013.  Sounds like a lot of work though, and you might be limited to a C API.

Comment: @PaulSanders if there's no other way then this is the only way.. is there an example of doing so?

Comment: @JackC. have you tried recompile the tibrv source?

Comment: @athos I don't have an example for you, sorry.  Learn how to write a DLL, exporting C functions or C++ classes and you should be on your way.  You can always wrap a C++ class in C by passing `this` around as a `void *` but if you're lucky VS2013 and VS2017 will share the same C++ ABI.  Maybe someone on SO knows if that's true or not.

Comment: @athos I have not tried to recompile.  The same manual states that source code for the C++ component is provided to allow users to recompile.  Also, you might be able to clear the __iob_func warning specifically by linking to "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib".

Comment: found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2#comment55259862_30894349) might be a solution.