# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am tryig to compile an application in VS2017 (C++) and I get the errors:

```
1>libeay32.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
1>libeay32.lib(pem_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
1>libeay32.lib(ui_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
```

Other posts reported on such an error are for VS2015 and refer to `stdin, stdout` and `stderr`. But those fixes have not worked for me.

Strangely, if I go to stdin in the code and (right click) go to definition it takes me to Visual Studio 11.0 include directories, not the VS2017 ones.

My error is in **libeay32.lib** which I can't find a C++ source for anywhere.

Has anybody else had this problem?

Comment: Looks like someone was directly messing around with the internals of `FILE` which is unsupported and not available in VS2015 and upwards.

Comment: Add C++ standard library to linker i.e. `msvcrt.lib`

Comment: @VictorGubin linking against MSVCRT is not supported or recommended and should be avoided for binary compatibility reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unresolved external symbol \_\_imp\_\_fprintf and \_\_imp\_\_\_\_iob\_func, SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2)

Comment: You are trying to link a library that was built with the wrong VS version.  And old one so you don't get a better linker error.  The IDE navigating to the wrong directory is another excellent hint.  You must obtain an up-to-date build of it.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution and added these lines to my VS 17 C++ project

```
#define stdin  (__acrt_iob_func(0))
#define stdout (__acrt_iob_func(1))
#define stderr (__acrt_iob_func(2))

FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };
extern "C" FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void) { return _iob; }

This worked for me.
```

Comment: Instead of just posting the code, please also explain how that works for you and/or what difference does it make