# How to solve mingw-w64 MSVCRT dependency issues

Tags: c++, go, compiler-errors, mingw-w64, msvcrt

I'm building a golang project by using Go1.12 + msys2/mingw-w64(9.2.0), it shows errors:

```
D:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o: in function `pre_c_init':
E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:146: undefined reference to `__p__fmode'
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o: in function `__tmainCRTStartup':
E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:290: undefined reference to `_set_invalid_parameter_handler'
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:299: undefined reference to `__p__acmdln'
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-merr.o): in function `_matherr':
E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/merr.c:46: undefined reference to `__acrt_iob_func'
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-pseudo-reloc.o): in function `__report_error':
E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/pseudo-reloc.c:149: undefined reference to `__acrt_iob_func'
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/pseudo-reloc.c:150: undefined reference to `__acrt_iob_func'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After some research I'm sure it's a msvcrt compatibility issue of mingw64.
I know there are workarounds like this: [unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf and __imp____iob_func, SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2)
But it doesn't solve all of my issues.

I try to link the library: LDFLAGS: -L%filepath% -llegacy_stdio_definitions, nothing changes.

Is there a patch to fix it, or do I have to build my custom version of mingw64?

Comment: Are you mixing files from two different tool-chains as this does not work?

Comment: @ Richard Critten  Why would I do that?

Comment: Because mingw-w64 does not use MSVCRT, it's got it's own  C runtime support library. So the question title prompted my comment.

Comment: @RichardCritten I've tested it on my machine. Even a simple 'hello world' binary appears to load `msvcrt.dll` at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I answer my question by myself, the case is closed.

Yes, Mingw64 uses msvcrt.

Here are some tips that could help to solve dependency problems between Mingw64 & msvcrt.
The major goal is to let compiler load the correct version of MSVCRT library family.

1.Update Mingw64.

2.Check out **MSVCRT_VERSION** in Mingw64\include_mingw.h(or x86_64-w64-mingw32\include), make sure the version number matches your windows version, or modify it.

3.Take a look at linker option like "#cgo LDFLAGS: -Lxxx", don't mess the library path. Remove any unnecessary library path setting, let linker finds libraries itself.

4. Make sure everything is built with same libraries.