# How Do I Compile Google Test Code With cl.exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, googletest

I am attempting to port some C++ files which run under Google Test (gtest) from a Linux development environment to a Windows development environment. I haven't used Visual Studio in about ten years and am more of a Linux guy so this may be a very ignorant question. How can I compile and link Google Test using the cl.exe compile of Visual Studio 2019?

I have a simple example test.cpp file:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I try to compile it with something like:

```
cl.exe /I "C:\gtest\include" main.cpp gtest.lib gtest_main.lib
```

This compiles for me but it does not link. I get 26 unresolved externals, such as __imp___dup, __imp___dup2, and __imp___creat. Is there something I am missing from my compile line?

The full output is as follows, but it may be messy as I am probably making an obvious mistake:

```
test.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ostream(746): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
C:\Users\dfarm\Source\Repos\Sample-Test1\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.3\build\native\include\gtest/gtest-message.h(106): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>    &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>    &,const char *)' being compiled
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29914.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe 
test.obj 
gtest.lib 
gtest_main.lib 
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: struct _Cvtvec __thiscall std::_Locinfo::_Getcvt(void)const " (?_Getcvt@_Locinfo@std@@QBE?AU_Cvtvec@@XZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned short const * __thiscall std::_Locinfo::_W_Getdays(void)const " (?_W_Getdays@_Locinfo@std@@QBEPBGXZ) already defined in libcpmt.lib(wlocale.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned short const * __thiscall std::_Locinfo::_W_Getmonths(void)const " (?_W_Getmonths@_Locinfo@std@@QBEPBGXZ) already defined in libcpmt.lib(wlocale.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >(void)" (??0?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::~basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >(void)" (??1?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::_Pninc(void)" (?_Pninc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEPADXZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::~basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >(void)" (??1?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::widen(char)const " (?widen@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDD@Z) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >(void)" (??0?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char        & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char        & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char        *)" (??0?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@@Z) already defined in test.obj
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >::~basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char    >(void)" (??1?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in test.obj
   Creating library test.lib and object test.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn' defined in 'libucrt.lib(invalid_parameter.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: class testing::Message & __thiscall testing::Message::operator<<<class testing::Message>(class testing::Message const &)" (??$?6VMessage@testing@@@Message@testing@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_calloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(calloc.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"wchar_t * __cdecl std::_Maklocwcs(wchar_t const *)" (?_Maklocwcs@std@@YAPA_WPB_W@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: __thiscall testing::internal::RE::~RE(void)" (??1RE@internal@testing@@QAE@XZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_malloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(malloc.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"private: void __thiscall testing::internal::RE::Init(char const *)" (?Init@RE@internal@testing@@AAEXPBD@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__errno' defined in 'libucrt.lib(errno.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"bool __cdecl testing::internal::ParseNaturalNumber<int>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        const &,int *)" (??$ParseNaturalNumber@H@internal@testing@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAH@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_exit' defined in 'libucrt.lib(exit.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"int __cdecl testing::internal::Int32FromEnvOrDie(char const *,int)" (?Int32FromEnvOrDie@internal@testing@@YAHPBDH@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__exit' defined in 'libucrt.lib(exit.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"protected: virtual void __thiscall testing::internal::DeathTestImpl::Abort(enum testing::internal::DeathTest::AbortReason)" (?Abort@DeathTestImpl@internal@testing@@MAEXW4AbortReason@DeathTest@23@@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_abort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(abort.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"void __cdecl testing::internal::posix::Abort(void)" (?Abort@posix@internal@testing@@YAXXZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__set_abort_behavior' defined in 'libucrt.lib(abort.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: int __thiscall testing::UnitTest::Run(void)" (?Run@UnitTest@testing@@QAEHXZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__set_error_mode' defined in 'libucrt.lib(set_error_mode.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: int __thiscall testing::UnitTest::Run(void)" (?Run@UnitTest@testing@@QAEHXZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strtol' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strtox.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"bool __cdecl testing::internal::ParseInt32(class testing::Message const &,char const *,int *)" (?ParseInt32@internal@testing@@YA_NABVMessage@2@PBDPAH@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__strtoui64' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strtox.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"bool __cdecl testing::internal::ParseNaturalNumber<int>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        const &,int *)" (??$ParseNaturalNumber@H@internal@testing@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAH@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_getenv' defined in 'libucrt.lib(getenv.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"bool __cdecl testing::internal::BoolFromGTestEnv(char const *,bool)" (?BoolFromGTestEnv@internal@testing@@YA_NPBD_N@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '___acrt_iob_func' defined in 'libucrt.lib(_file.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: __thiscall testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog(void)" (??1GTestLog@internal@testing@@QAE@XZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__wcsicmp' defined in 'libucrt.lib(wcsicmp.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: static bool __cdecl testing::internal::String::CaseInsensitiveWideCStringEquals(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (?CaseInsensitiveWideCStringEquals@String@internal@testing@@SA_NPB_W0@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fclose' defined in 'libucrt.lib(fclose.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        __cdecl testing::internal::GetCapturedStream(class testing::internal::CapturedStream * *)" (?GetCapturedStream@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAPAVCapturedStream@12@@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fflush' defined in 'libucrt.lib(fflush.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: __thiscall testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog(void)" (??1GTestLog@internal@testing@@QAE@XZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__fileno' defined in 'libucrt.lib(fileno.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"void __cdecl testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(enum testing::internal::GTestColor,char const *,...)" (?ColoredPrintf@internal@testing@@YAXW4GTestColor@12@PBDZZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fputc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(fputc.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"void __cdecl testing::internal::DeathTestAbort(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        const &)" (?DeathTestAbort@internal@testing@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '___stdio_common_vfprintf' defined in 'libucrt.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"void __cdecl testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(enum testing::internal::GTestColor,char const *,...)" (?ColoredPrintf@internal@testing@@YAXW4GTestColor@12@PBDZZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '___stdio_common_vsnprintf_s' defined in 'libucrt.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '__snprintf_s'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strncmp' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strncmp.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"char const * __cdecl testing::internal::ParseFlagValue(char const *,char const *,bool)" (?ParseFlagValue@internal@testing@@YAPBDPBD0_N@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_isdigit' defined in 'libucrt.lib(_ctype.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"bool __cdecl testing::internal::ParseNaturalNumber<int>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        const &,int *)" (??$ParseNaturalNumber@H@internal@testing@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAH@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_isxdigit' defined in 'libucrt.lib(_ctype.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"enum testing::internal::CharFormat __cdecl testing::internal::PrintCharsAsStringTo<char>(char const *,unsigned int,class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char        *)" (??$PrintCharsAsStringTo@D@internal@testing@@YA?AW4CharFormat@01@PBDIPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_isspace' defined in 'libucrt.lib(_ctype.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"class testing::AssertionResult __cdecl testing::internal::`anonymous namespace'::HRESULTFailureHelper(char const *,char const *,long)" (?HRESULTFailureHelper@?A0x0fcd2788@internal@testing@@YA?AVAssertionResult@3@PBD0J@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_iscntrl' defined in 'libucrt.lib(_ctype.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"bool __cdecl testing::internal::`anonymous namespace'::ContainsUnprintableControlCodes(char const *,unsigned int)" (?ContainsUnprintableControlCodes@?A0x0fcd2788@internal@testing@@YA_NPBDI@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_toupper' defined in 'libucrt.lib(tolower_toupper.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        __cdecl testing::internal::FlagToEnvVar(char const *)" (?FlagToEnvVar@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PBD@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__isatty' defined in 'libucrt.lib(isatty.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"void __cdecl testing::internal::ColoredPrintf(enum testing::internal::GTestColor,char const *,...)" (?ColoredPrintf@internal@testing@@YAXW4GTestColor@12@PBDZZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__open_osfhandle' defined in 'libucrt.lib(osfinfo.obj)' is imported by 'gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)' in function '"public: virtual enum testing::internal::DeathTest::TestRole __thiscall testing::internal::WindowsDeathTest::AssumeRole(void)" (?AssumeRole@WindowsDeathTest@internal@testing@@UAE?AW4TestRole@DeathTest@23@XZ)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '__close' defined in 'libucrt.lib(close.obj)' is imported by 'OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '__read' defined in 'libucrt.lib(read.obj)' is imported by 'OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '__write' defined in 'libucrt.lib(write.obj)' is imported by 'OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi)'
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___stat64i32 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall testing::internal::FilePath::DirectoryExists(void)const " (?DirectoryExists@FilePath@internal@testing@@QBE_NXZ)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fopen referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        __cdecl testing::internal::GetCapturedStream(class testing::internal::CapturedStream * *)" (?GetCapturedStream@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAPAVCapturedStream@12@@Z)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fread referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        __cdecl testing::internal::ReadEntireFile(struct _iobuf *)" (?ReadEntireFile@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAU_iobuf@@@Z)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fseek referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl testing::internal::GetFileSize(struct _iobuf *)" (?GetFileSize@internal@testing@@YAIPAU_iobuf@@@Z)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ftell referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl testing::internal::GetFileSize(struct _iobuf *)" (?GetFileSize@internal@testing@@YAIPAU_iobuf@@@Z)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fwrite referenced in function "public: int __thiscall testing::UnitTest::Run(void)" (?Run@UnitTest@testing@@QAEHXZ)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__remove referenced in function "public: __thiscall testing::internal::ScopedPrematureExitFile::~ScopedPrematureExitFile(void)" (??1ScopedPrematureExitFile@internal@testing@@QAE@XZ)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fdopen referenced in function "struct _iobuf * __cdecl testing::internal::posix::FDOpen(int,char const *)" (?FDOpen@posix@internal@testing@@YAPAU_iobuf@@HPBD@Z)
OLDNAMES.lib(fdopen.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fdopen
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___strdup referenced in function "private: void __thiscall testing::internal::RE::Init(char const *)" (?Init@RE@internal@testing@@AAEXPBD@Z)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__strerror referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char        __cdecl testing::internal::GetLastErrnoDescription(void)" (?GetLastErrnoDescription@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___stricmp referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl testing::internal::String::CaseInsensitiveCStringEquals(char const *,char const *)" (?CaseInsensitiveCStringEquals@String@internal@testing@@SA_NPBD0@Z)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___getcwd referenced in function "public: static class testing::internal::FilePath __cdecl testing::internal::FilePath::GetCurrentDir(void)" (?GetCurrentDir@FilePath@internal@testing@@SA?AV123@XZ)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___mkdir referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall testing::internal::FilePath::CreateFolder(void)const " (?CreateFolder@FilePath@internal@testing@@QBE_NXZ)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__close referenced in function "void __cdecl testing::internal::CaptureStream(int,char const *,class testing::internal::CapturedStream * *)" (?CaptureStream@internal@testing@@YAXHPBDPAPAVCapturedStream@12@@Z)
OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__close
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__creat referenced in function "void __cdecl testing::internal::CaptureStream(int,char const *,class testing::internal::CapturedStream * *)" (?CaptureStream@internal@testing@@YAXHPBDPAPAVCapturedStream@12@@Z)
OLDNAMES.lib(creat.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__creat
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dup referenced in function "void __cdecl testing::internal::CaptureStream(int,char const *,class testing::internal::CapturedStream * *)" (?CaptureStream@internal@testing@@YAXHPBDPAPAVCapturedStream@12@@Z)
OLDNAMES.lib(dup.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__dup
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dup2 referenced in function "void __cdecl testing::internal::CaptureStream(int,char const *,class testing::internal::CapturedStream * *)" (?CaptureStream@internal@testing@@YAXHPBDPAPAVCapturedStream@12@@Z)
OLDNAMES.lib(dup2.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__dup2
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__read referenced in function "void __cdecl testing::internal::FailFromInternalError(int)" (?FailFromInternalError@internal@testing@@YAXH@Z)
OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__read
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__write referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall testing::internal::DeathTestImpl::Abort(enum testing::internal::DeathTest::AbortReason)" (?Abort@DeathTestImpl@internal@testing@@MAEXW4AbortReason@DeathTest@23@@Z)
OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__write
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___localtime64_s referenced in function "bool __cdecl testing::internal::PortableLocaltime(__int64,struct tm *)" (?PortableLocaltime@internal@testing@@YA_N_JPAUtm@@@Z)
gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___ftime64 referenced in function "__int64 __cdecl testing::internal::GetTimeInMillis(void)" (?GetTimeInMillis@internal@testing@@YA_JXZ)
OLDNAMES.lib(fdopen.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___fdopen
OLDNAMES.lib(creat.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___creat
OLDNAMES.lib(dup.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___dup
OLDNAMES.lib(dup2.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___dup2
MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 26 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Q: So did the links I cited - and the suggestions therein - help?  Note, too, your error messages: `'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in test.obj` and `defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`.  Finally, I ASSUME you've rebuilt "gtest" from source.  A  binary library built with Gnu++ (for example) *WILL NOT LINK* with a library built using a different compiler (e.g. MSVC++). 
 Please update your post with what you've tried, and the results.

Comment: I did try adding /MT, and no luck. I also tried adding User32.lib to the list of libs. Neither worked. I am currently trying to see if I can find out how Visual Studio 2019 compiles the code when it is in a project in hopes I can find the right params from it.

Comment: Q: Are you rebuilding all source in MSVS?  If not, exactly which binaries (.lib, .dll, .obj) weren't you able to build from source? Q: Were you able to follow these instructions, and follow them EXACTLY: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2019? If not, where did you need to deviate?  Note that the instructions use the IDE (not "cl").

Comment: So yes, I am building all my source using MSVS. However, I am trying to create a scripted build which starts with understanding how to do this from the cl.exe compiler. I started with the link provided, and hoped to pull the source and the .libs out of the MSVS project and compile on the command prompt. I have been frustrated assuming this looks more like g++ than it really does.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: 1) Follow the given instructions.  2) Get it to work.  At that point, you can definitely take what you learned, generate a "makefile", and use "cl" to your heart's content :)  But until then, you're likely to "flounder" :(

Comment: Q: Are you successfully able to build a test exe (using the IDE)?  Have you passed that hurdle?  As far as "command line", are you comfortable with Make (or equivalent)?  Versus manually typing the "cl" commands?  I imagine that's probably how you've been using gcc - running "make" (instead of typing individual g++/gcc commands).  Correct?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do the command line as a step to getting to the Makefile. I can use nmake for some simple examples without Google Test. I am able to build out of the IDE as a starting point. If I can get the IDE to generate a Makefile, I could do a dry-run to see how the command line works.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, dup(), dup2(), creat() and friends are all "standard" C library functions ("standard" as "commonly available") ... that Visual Studio treats "differently".

SUGGESTION: try static linking, e.g.  `/MT`:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56698430/421195
>
> Change your Runtime library settings as below
>
> `Project properties --> C/C++ --> Code generation --> Runtime Library --> Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) instead of /MDd`

See also: [Unable to compile VIX Programs](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VIX-API-Discussions/Unable-to-compile-VIX-Programs/m-p/2099682)